# Zoom not launching on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, kernel

I installed Zoom on my Ubuntu machine, The app is not launching at all 
I looked into syslog

`$ tail -f syslog`

```
Apr  6 12:47:09 MACHINENAME kernel: [ 6778.914376] zoom[25201]: segfault at ffffff00 ip 00007f9c6fc83cc0 sp 00007ffd4d9b03a0 error 4 in libc-2.23.so[7f9c6fc35000+1c0000]
```

`$ uname -a`

```
Linux MACHINENAME 4.13.0-37-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 7 16:03:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, network drivers were not claimed so I had to upgrade kernel with below command

`$ sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Zoom support, This was the response,

> The Previous version of Zoom did not create this file path, so we have to add it manually by using `touch ~/.config/zoomus.conf`
>
> That creates the configuration folder and when Zoom runs during install, the files are populated.

Comment: Nop, not working.