# Zoom does not launch properly in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, zoom-meeting

I'm trying to run zoom on ubuntu 18.04, but it won't launch. I installed from their official release. Now, when I launch zoom (either with the `zoom` command or using the gui launch) the frame is either totally clear (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeJxi.jpg)) or sometimes I can see the login button, but can't click on it. I've tried solutions to these three similar questions, none of which have worked:

- [Zoom not launching on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022488/zoom-not-launching-on-ubuntu-16-04)
- [Zoom not opening in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224370/zoom-not-opening-in-ubuntu-18-04)
- [zoom problem in launching through desktop app](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1212076/zoom-problem-in-launching-through-desktop-app)

I'm running the proprietary nvidia drivers. This is in the `~/.zoom/logs/zoom_stdout_stderr.log` file:

```
ZoomLauncher started.
Zoom path is: /opt/zoom
cmd line:
CreateReportChannel bp_server_fd=4
$HOME = /home/<my home!>
export SSB_HOME=/home/<my home!>/.zoom; export QSG_INFO=1; export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCA
LE_FACTOR=1; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/zoom; export BREAKPAD_CLIENT_FD=3; /o
pt/zoom/zoom ""
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
zoom started.
[CZPClientLogMgr::LogClientEnvironment] [MacAddr: 74:D0:2B:C7:82:3C][client: L
inux][OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS][Hardware: CPU Core:4 Frenquency:3.5 G Memory siz
e:15951MB CPU Brand:Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770K CPU @ 3.50GHz GPU Brand:][Req I
D: ]
Linux Client Version is 5.2.446620.0816
QSG_RENDER_LOOP is
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = ubuntu:GNOME;   GDMSESSION = ubuntu
Graphics Card Info:: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK1
10 [GeForce GTX 780] (rev a1)
Zoom package arch is 64bit, runing OS arch is x86_64
qt.scenegraph.general: threaded render loop
qt.scenegraph.general: Using sg animation driver
qt.scenegraph.general: Animation Driver: using vsync: 16.67 ms
qt.svg: link image0 hasn't been detected!
qt.svg: :/images/wechat.svg:10:6: Could not resolve property: pattern0
success to create child process,status is 2.
zoom  exited abnormally.
ZoomLauncher exit.
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: Switch to X.Org X server driver and it should work.

Zoom seems to have trouble with the proprietary nvidia driver(s). I have a similiar error log. Maybe zoom will fix this sometime, but it seems to be that X.Org is better tested & supported.